# Are secret stashes worth it?

Tags: savings

To rid the question of the "generality" tag, perhaps I should mention that I'd just like to know the top 5 most used techniques.

I first heard about this from the movie "Pain and Gain" (which is based on a true story), where the rich guy has a secret stash of money in a bank account that nobody else knows of.

Is it really legally possible to create such secret stashes?

**Three scenario's I'm considering:**

- Perhaps one would not want to disclose to one's spouse, a certain
  amount of money.
- Perhaps one would want to access this secret stash if somebody
  bankrupts him or steals his identity and steals his money.
- Or if war erupts or the bank liquidates and it isn't possible to
  access the money in one's bank account?

Do people create such stashes, and what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Your question is rather broad.  It's not clear what sorts of circumstances you're envisioning (i.e., how "secret" is the stash).  You can certainly put money in a bank account and not tell anyone about it in the course of your daily life.  But if you have to disclose your assets in a legally significant matter (e.g., you declare bankruptcy) and you don't disclose the secret money, you're probably breaking the law and/or exposing yourself to civil liability.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for clarifying that. The objective of the question was to ask about whether people create such stashes legally, and what options are available? If illegally, then is it worth it? The circumstances are something I wanted to know about, if someone on this forum is knowledgeable about these matters. If I had to specify a circumstance, it'd be about a situation where someone is either bent on ruining a guy or stealing from a guy and takes everything, but the guy has a secret stash which he can later access and not have to depend on anyone for help.

Comment: People have done it. Why they do it and what benefit they hope to get depends entirely on that person's concerns. This is too general a question to be answerable; the list is unending.

Comment: I think the most general answer to this question is simply *"No, it's just nonsense in a movie"*. Particularly if you're in the US, in broad general terms, no, you can't legally have "secret bank accounts".  It's just a bit of nonsense from movies.  It's like, one *hundred* years ago there were things like "secret numbered bank accounts in Lichtenstein" but it's just ancient history now.

Comment: Ok, it's good to know that it's nonsense in today's world. Of course there are people who store black money in Swiss bank accounts and tax havens in Morocco, but the government is catching them now.

Comment: Of course secret bank accounts still exist in places like Switzerland but you'll need $10m minimum as they don't like dealing with loose change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it worth it? That is for you to judge.

The risks are having it blowup in your face, and you having to pay a penalty, or go to jail.

The issue is how you keep it secret, and who you keep it secret from.

If you have money in a secret account and keep it hidden even though you:

- file your taxes;
- have to file for bankruptcy;
- get divorced;
- apply for financial aid;

You are taking a big risk.

If the knowledge of the contents of the secret stash would cause a judge or government agency to make a different decision, you could face penalties ranging from monetary to jail time.

The government could also decide that they need to determine the source of the funds. They may want to know if the money was "earned" through illegal means. They will want to determine if the funds should haven taxed not just on the interest but if the original income tax was ever collected.

If the amounts are large enough the taxing authority  and police will have a lot of fun pulling apart your entire financial history. Oh and the lawyers you pay to keep you out of jail will also have their fun.

why do some people do it? They are greedy; or paranoid; or they don't trust others; or they are criminals.

Answer (score 2):

Asset protection is broad subject.

In your examples it is certainly possible to have accounts that exist undisclosed from a spouse and legally inaccessible by said spouse.

In the US, balances in 401k retirement accounts are exempt from forfeitures in bankruptcy.

The only trick to secret stashes is that it involves you having any wealth in the first place, that you don't need to access. It is more worth it, for most people, to use all of their access to wealth to get out of debt, earn claims to property, and save for retirement. This takes up all of their earnings, making hidden wealth of any significant portion to be an impractical pipe dream.

But with trust laws, corporate laws, and marriage property laws being different in practically every jurisdiction, there is plenty of flexibility to construct the form of your secret wealth.  Cryptocurrency makes it **much** easier, at the expense of net asset value volatility.

Comment: Note that stealing from a spouse is ... still stealing. Legal term is embezzling, and it is a crime. So while you can make a "secret" stash, the legality of it would be dubious.

Comment: @littleadv a properly constructed account will be legally inaccessible in the jurisdiction it is formed in, while the court in your jurisdiction will try to legally undermine it if they find out, the forfeiture order will continue to fail. which is why I will stick with saying legally inaccessible.

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can stash your stolen goods somewhere where they can be legally inaccessible by the legal owners. But it won't be very much accessible to you from jail either.

Answer (score 1):

The goldbug crowd over on ZeroHedge's comments seem fond of reminding everyone that, while they might have bought and owned some gold in the past, they don't have it any more because they actually lost it all in a lake in "a tragic boating accident".  *And who's going to prove otherwise?*

For that group, who are convinced cash ("fiat paper") will at some point be worthless, the stockmarket will evaporate, the highest grade bonds will default and bank accounts and other personal assets will be subject to confiscation and "bail in"... general bug-out apocalypse in other words... having a "secret stash" of high-value physical assets is obviously quite important and reassuring and presumably totally "worth it".

Comment: In this case, it's guns, ammo, food, supplies, right? As I read Anon's question, it sounded like cash hidden from a potential ex spouse or creditor.

Comment: I'm sure all those things are in their "secret stashes" too, but they seem convinced gold is the only currency and "store of value" which will endure in the long run (although silver also seems popular... but not diamonds).  But putting survivalist stuff aside, some bars of shiny stuff buried out in the woods would presumably be equally effectively hidden from spouses or creditors (although the ZH-ers main worry seems to be the government).

Comment: Why not diamonds? Oskar Schindler had bribed Nazis with diamonds, telling them that in times of trouble, they'd need this "portable money". Of course, diamonds wouldn't survive a fire, but otherwise, aren't diamonds more easy to transport and conceal?

Comment: Because the postwar diamond market has been thoroughly rigged by DeBeers (classic 1982 article with much of the history: http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1982/02/have-you-ever-tried-to-sell-a-diamond/304575/ ; see also http://priceonomics.com/post/45768546804/diamonds-are-bullshit ).  If diamonds really were as credible and "investable" as a commodity as gold, silver, any other metal... there'd be ETFs/ETPs specializing them.  It should set pretty big alarm bells ringing that such things don't exist (although I believe there may be a diamond *miners* one).